# resize button image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want the following button (and it's image) to change size when I click it. The dialog is showing, but the size is not changing..

```
<html>
    <input type="image" src="pacman.png"  onClick="
        alert('test');
        this.height='200px'; // change de button size
        // this.image.height='200px'; // not sure if this line will work..
    "/>
</html>
```

Need be in javascript, no in the css, becouse I'll make an animation later..

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all?  If so, you can handle clicks and size changes easily.  ie: $('#button').click(function(){$(this).css('height','200px');}); -- I don't advocate doing inline javascript like in your example, but if you're not using javascript elsewhere and don't need a library like jQuery, it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to manipulate the "style" property:

```
this.style.height = '200px';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with

```
this.style.height = "200px";
```

BUT, you should look into jQuery, an excellent Javascript library which makes it really easy to do that plus a **LOT more**! It's worth the small learning curve, trust me. http://www.jquery.com